# Jquery turn off box-shadow on load

Tags: jquery, css

I have some elements that have a CSS3 box-shadow around them as default, if the user has javascript turned on though I would like to hide the box-shadow.

I am currently using the code seen below to hide other elements and this method works perfectly except for the box-shadow. I have done a few tests, i.e put other code where 'box-shadow:none' is and it always works as expected, I therefore assume it's a problem with the compatibility of the CSS3 box-shadow attribute and jquery.

Can anyone think of a way to get around this? Or maybe another way to turn off the box-shadow attribute on load of the page.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
$('html').append('<style type="text/css">.sub-menu{width:897px;display:none;} .sub-menu-header{box-shadow:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;}</style>');
```

CSS for the sub-menu-header

```
.sub-menu-header{
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
   border:1px solid #CCC;
   cursor:pointer; 
}
```

Comment: Has the `box-shadow` been set with the same selector [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) (`.sub-menu-header`)?

Comment: Yes it has, i have added the css code for the sub-menu-header to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a no-js class to your html tag: `<html class="no-js">`

Add your styles:

```
.no-js .sub-menu-header{
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}
.sub-menu-header{
   border:1px solid #CCC;
   cursor:pointer; 
}
```

Then just remove the no-js class in your javascript file:

```
$("html").removeClass("no-js");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot modify your css, a better way to do it is by using jQuery's *css* method. Be sure if the box-shadow property isn't specified any other way than by the class selector in your css:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".sub-menu-header").css("box-shadow", "none");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, although this would work, the box-shadow would flash up before it was hidden and I do not wish for the user to see anything